# Cron job can't get it to run, What syntax to use for the crontab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to get a rails job running with CRON. All the examples I find direct me to other rails tools, plugins, gems, etc, which is good, but I really just want to use CRON, regardless.  I can run my job ok with the following, but when I've tried cron I haven't had any luck (just doesn't seem to do anything).  I want to run it every 3 minutes (for testing).

```
/usr/bin/env ruby ~/Dropbox/98_2011/webs/apps238/swapper/script/runner /home/durrantm/Dropbox/98_2011/webs/apps238/swapper/app/controllers/scheduled_emails_controller.rb
```

I'm on Linux Ubuntu.

My PATH has:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/bin:/home/durrantm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/pgsql/bin
```

Comment: If you're running a recent version of Ubuntu you might have better luck with upstart.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks that's a good suggestion.  Is it available on most linux these days? I should have explained that once I have got it running on my box, my ISP is next and I don't know if they would have it.  I did 'man upstart' in my shell there and it's not found unlike my local (Ubuntu) box.

Comment: Upstart has been in Ubuntu since 6.10, Fedora since version 9 IIRC, SuSE has it, not sure about others- you might want to google it. I know things like Palm's WebOS use it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron jobs don't load the user's environment. Try adding RAILS_ENV=production before your command within crontab, or whichever environment you need.

Example:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
*/3 * * * * /your/command/here
```

OR, if you want to make sure you have your user's full environment, execute the command within a login shell:

```
*/3 * * * * bash --login -c '/your/command/here'
```

Comment: do I just put that line in the actual crontab file before the * * * *, etc... line?

Comment: I tried the first but it didn't help, I still get  'Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler`
I tried the second (including the login shell) and itran (lots of output about my enviromental variables).  but still didn't seem to really run the job, just no errors. ?

Comment: Try adding a redirect after the job to capture all output, behind the command but inside the quotes: '/your/command > /tmp/cron.log 2>&1', and check that for errors.

Comment: I tried bash --login -c  /usr/bin/env ruby '/home/durrantm/Dropbox/98_2011/webs/apps238/swapper/script/runner /home/durrantm/Dropbox/98_2011/webs/apps238/swapper/app/controllers/scheduled_emails_controller.rb > /tmp/cron.log 2> &1'

Comment: i get lots of environment varfiables info but no err msg and the job (which sends emails) doesn't do what it does (send the emails) if I run it from the command line.

Comment: Well then I'm not quite sure what else to suggest, other then checking if the process runs at all from cron (i.e. in the rails log files).

Comment: Thx anyway, Thilio, wish this was easier.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the home dir expansion character (replace ~ with /home/user/etc/etc) and you should be in good shape (quite likely cron's expansion of ~ doesn't match your users).

If the other parts of the syntax are bothersome there's an easy gui.

http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/

`sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule`

You'll still have to have the path to your rb file fixed up though.

Comment: good catch,. I had just realized that too and changed it.  No luck yet but I will check more on the link you've provided.  Thank You.  Michael.

Comment: I used the GNOME gui (great tool) and ran it once from there and was able toi see: /home/durrantm/Dropbox/98_2011/webs/apps238/swapper/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:5: Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler`. (RuntimeError)
Do you know how to get past that?  Seems like it's still not finding my environment correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1- you might not have permissions. try running crontab -e as root

2- why don't you write to a log file to debug the issue:

*/3 * * * * /your/command/here >> /path/to/logfile

Comment: Thanks very much Anas :)
I tried that but unfortunately neither gave any output

* * * * * bash --login -c /usr/bin/env ruby /home/durrantm/Dropbox/98_2011/webs/apps238/swapper/script/runner /home/durrantm/Dropbox/98_2011/webs/apps238/swapper/app/controllers/scheduled_emails_controller.rb >> /home/durrantm # JOB_ID_1